# how to change react state from other file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have reactJs files. And I need to use state from first file in second, to change state in first from second file)
P.S. i need change (test: false (need-> true)) from class B(other file).

```js
class A extends Component {
  this.state = {
            test: false
        };
}

////////////////
class B extends Component {
  

}
```

Comment: Read this carefully: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: Your component A and B are in the same tree (normally `App`) component. So, @Stretch0's answer work since you can lift the state up to your `App` component.

Comment: But @Stretch0's answer change A from Parent, not from B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use redux, or handle the state in the parent component and pass it down like so:

```
class A extends Component {
  // ...
}


class B extends Component {

  updateTestInB(){
    this.props.updateTest(true)
  }

}

class Parent extends Component {

    state = {
        test: false
    }

    updateTest(boolean){
        this.setState({test: !this.state.test})
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <a test={this.state.test} />
                <b updateTest={this.updateTest}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't create 1 more file only for one state
Is there are any other way to change state in class A?

Comment: Why you can't create 1 more file? This example is the correct way of doing such changes. There is a parent "Stateful" component, and a child "stateless component" which updates the parents state via a callback function.

Comment: but i need change A from B, not from Parent(

Comment: That's not helpful just saying "it didn't working". Why don't you update your post with how more information and how you implemented it and maybe we can try assist. This is a common pattern in React. For some reason you seem to be against it so maybe you could look at using Redux for handling global state?